# Alpha animation for "fading in" an image?

Tags: android

I have an image that I would like to slowly fade in; I've played around with the standard animation constructs, but it never seems to work.

(Code for the image:)

```
@Override
    public void draw(Canvas c, Layer layer) {
        if ( layer == Layer.BACKGROUND ) {              

            Animation a = new AlphaAnimation(1.00f, 0.00f);
            a.setDuration(4000);

            instructions.startAnimation(a);

            location.left = (view.getWidth() - instructions.getMinimumWidth() ) /2;
            location.right = location.left + instructions.getMinimumWidth();
            location.top = view.getHeight() / 2;
            location.bottom = location.top + instructions.getMinimumHeight();
            instructions.setBounds(location);
            instructions.draw(c);
        }
        //explosions.draw(c, layer);
    }
};
```

... "startAnimation is undefined for the type BitmapDrawable," it says.

Answer (score 0):

The `startAnimation` is a method of a `View`, so if you have the bitmap in an `ImageView` instance `imageView`, you should call `imageView.startAnimation(a);`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it in code, consider doing it using XML: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#View